Why did old RISC processors that required word-aligned loads and stores still use byte addressing?
I know most of those architectures added unaligned loads and stores later on, but when they first started, as far as I know, they were effectively word-aligned (faulting on any non-word aligned address) despite using byte aligned addresses. So why still use byte-addressing? I asked Chat-GPT, but it just talked about the benefits of byte-addressing.

After checking again, it seems that these architectures required natural-alignment, not word-alignment. This answers my question.

You are welcome to answer your own question. After two days, you can accept your answer to indicate the question doesn't need further attention. Don't try to answer in a comment, the purpose of a comment shall be to get the post improved.
